# An error when declaring the variable placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, pycharm

I am building sample Neural Network using Pycharm, tensorflow 2.4 and python v3.8.5. When Running this command:

```
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_input])   #num_input is the sized of input vector
```

I get an error like this one:

```
raise TypeError("Error converting %s to a TensorShape: %s." % (arg_name, e))

TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got value '8.0' with type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'.
```

What is the problem of that error?  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This row (tf.placeholder) is enable for tensorflow 1, but you have installed tensorflow2. Disable Tf2 and run your backend on Tf1 .

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 8])

print(X)
<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(?, 8) dtype=float32>
```

Comment: Thank, I am using these two lines; import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()      By the way I think Tf1 is more stable compared with Tf2,  I am trying to solve the issue by installing TF1 instead of Tf2.

Comment: Happy Coding !!